# Displaying retentioneering interactable graph in a web app with flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm using [retentioneering library](https://retentioneering.github.io/retentioneering-tools/_build/html/index.html) with python for analysing complex user behaviors in a website and show it as a graph.
Everything works as expected but now, I would like to provide access to this plots also to other people using a web app built with flask.

This is the result given from retentioneering: [retentioneering graph result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcAum.png) where you can select various "filters" and drag node to change their location.
I would like to create a web app with this exact graph and filters provided by the library plus, as I said, the drop down.

The problem is that the graph is not just an image but something a user can interact with, so my question is: how can I show it in a dynamic way like [here](https://retentioneering.github.io/retentioneering-tools/_build/html/plot_graph.html#before-you-start)? Is there some specific html object I should use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Investigating a bit more on how retentioneering works it turns out that the final return value is basically an html with javascript that create the graph.
So using flask displaying this html is really straightforward using the render_template function.